# java - Why is hashCode() in Object instead of a separate interface?

Tags: java, hash, hashcode

First I wish to state that I'm aware of the javadoc of `java.lang.Object.hashCode()` and thus there's no need to mention it again.

What I'm asking is: **Why isn't `java.lang.Object.hashCode()` moved into a seperate interface named (probably) `Hashable`? Like `java.lang.Comparator'?**

To me, `hashCode()` is only used in hash-dependent data structures like `HashMap` or `HashTable`, which a) are not used in every application b) are often used with very few types of keys like `String` or `Integer` and not with a `InputStream` (or something like it).

I know that I do not have to implement `hashCode()` for every class of mine, however, isn't adding a method to a class at the cost of performance to some extent? Especially for `java.lang.Object` - the superclass of every class in Java.

Even if special optimization is done within the JVM so that the lost of performance can be ignored, I still think that it's unwise to provide every `Object` with a behavior that is not frequently implemented at all. According to the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle):

> No client should be forced to depend on methods it does not use.

I did some searches in the web and the only related page I could find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096028/why-gethashcode-is-in-object-class).

The first answer expressed (partly) the same idea as mine, and some others tried to answer the question, saying mainly that "`hashCode()` for every `Object` enables storage of object of any type in `HashMap`", which I take as not satisfactory.

I here propose **my own solution**, which satisfies both the Interface Segregation Principle and the ability to store anything in a `HashMap` without adding much complexity the whole system:

1. Remove `hashCode()` from `java.lang.Object`.
2. Let there be an interface `Hashable`, containing `hashCode()` with the same contract as the former `java.lang.Object.hashCode()`.
3. Let there be an interface `HashProvider` with a type parameter `T` containing `provideHashCode(T t)` to provide a hash code for an object. (Think of `Comparator<T>`).
4. Let there be an implementation of `HashProvider<Object>` called `DefaultHashProvider` which generates the hash code for any `Object` using the current implementation of `Object.hashCode()`. (As for Java 8, Object.hashCode() is a native method, I expect `DefaultHashProvider.provideHashCode()` to return the same thing for any `Object`)
5. Modify constructors of `HashMap` and `HashTable` so that everything can be stored in them by:

   1. Using the `provideHashCode()` if a `HashProvider` is specified.
   2. Using the `hashCode()` if its underlying elements implement `Hashable`.
   3. Using `DefaultHashProvider` otherwise.

I believe that this is possible in practice because it's just a variation of the system of `Comparable`, `Comparator` and `TreeMap`.

And let my repeat **my question**:

Considering that the Java development team should not be unable to come up with a solution similar to mine, is there any good reason for not doing so? Are there some advanced considerations that I'm currently unaware of? I have the following hypotheses, does any of them approach the correct answer?

1. Some language features required by this solution, like generic types, are available only well after the very beginning of Java - since 1.5. However, I would argue that `Comparator`, `Comparable` along with `TreeMap` exist since 1.2, can't the technique used to write them be adapted to `HashMap`?
2. `hashCode()` is used somewhere within the JVM and therefore it requires every `Object` to have a hash code. However this can also be available using `DefaultHashProvider.provideHashCode()` (or its native implementation) for non-hashables.

Comment: a simple note aside of it making sense or not: It´s not changable as it would break backward compatibility.

Comment: Why not asking the same for every `Object` method then?

Comment: In case of `Comparator`, being comparable doesn't makes sense for every object, but being Hashable does.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I do find that most methods in `Object` are appropriate, like `getClass()` etc. I'm only asking about this specific one, `hashCode()`.

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy So is it really a design mistake, placing `hashCode()` inside `Object`? Just for compatibility this cannot be amended?

Comment: It won't be changed, no. Some libraries provide a "hashable" mechanism for these kinds of operations, but the JDK won't ever move `hashCode` out of `Object`. There are far more minor oddities that still remain in there, so something this big would never fly.

Comment: But your args like "hashcode is only used in..." can't be translated for every Object method. Anyway. "design mistake" maybe, but Java is an old language now,and these kind of considerations are much newer. And, YES compatibility is a very good argument too.

Comment: @std4453 it might be and one can argue about it, but removing the `hashCode` from `Object` is a big nono, as the java version forcing these wouldn´t be able to execute java code compiled in lower version (one of the main goals is the ability to execute code done in lower java version). That´s the point for me where one could theoretically talk about it beeing structured well enough, but it´s simply impossible to change. This might lead to the same type of discussion as [the Discussion why one is able to execute static methods on object instances](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610458/1799530)

Comment: `hashCode` is also part of the contract for `equals` so you can't move it out of `java.lang.Object`

Comment: Every software project has some legacy.
Why are concerned about `hashCode` only?
There is a method called `finalize` which is considered harmful and not recommended for use. It's still there!

For most of the "why" questions in Java you will get an answer - backward compatibility. Which is (or at least was) an important selling point.

If you want more info one option is to use twitter - many of java platform developers/contributors are there. You can post this SO link there and mention someone.

Comment: @Admit [`java.lang.Object.finalize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize--) is deprecated in Java 9, but yes, it will never be removed because of backward compatibility.

Comment: Saying "is only used in hash-dependent data structures like HashMap or HashTable" ignores that these structures allow fast access to instances. It means that internal Java systems can organize all Java objects efficiently instead of just instances that implement Hashable.

Comment: @JimW Well I think I've stated this clear enough... I understand that some applications might want every `Object` to have a hash code, however this does not mean that `hashCode()` must be in `Object` - it can be somewhere else, like in the solution I've proposed in the question.

Comment: I guess you didn't read my comment entirely or maybe you're just a troll, but I mentioned it's likely important to the JVM, the internal Java systems that are written in guess what, Java! It's likely that for efficiency sake the JVM wants every object to be Hashable. Every Object, not just objects that implement Hashable.